# How to add bean instance at runtime in spring WebApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So, the title is pretty straightforward. I have a handler class `DynamicBeanHandler` which implements `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` interface provided by spring. In this class I'm adding multiple `SCOPE_SINGLETON` beans which have bean class set as `MyDynamicBean` as follows-

```
GenericBeanDefinition myBeanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
myBeanDefinition.setBeanClass(MyDynamicBean.class);
myBeanDefinition.setScope(SCOPE_SINGLETON);
myBeanDefinition.setPropertyValues(getMutableProperties(dynamicPropertyPrefix));
registry.registerBeanDefinition(dynamicBeanId, myBeanDefinition);
```

The method `getMutableProperties()` returns an object of `MutablePropertyValues`.

Later on, I do `SpringUtil.getBean(dynamicBeanId)` to fetch the required `MyDynamicBean` instance where `SpringUtil` class implements `ApplicationContextAware`. All this works great. The problem comes when I want to remove one of these instances and add a new instance later on where I don't have the registry instance. Can anyone please help me find a way to do this?

Following is the code for class `SpringUtil`-

```
public class SpringUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String beanId) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanId);
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String beanId, Class<T> beanClass) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanId, beanClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Are you trying to delay initialization?

Comment: So, I want to do it because `MyDynamicBean` contains some properties which I want to update from database programatically at runtime. Please note that I want to update the bean instance after context has been initialized and add a new bean instance.

Comment: @Abhishek Can you post the code of your current `SpringUtil`?

Comment: @javaguy - Updated the code. Please check.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can make use of `BeanDefinitionRegistry` (look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry.html) for API) to remove or register the beans dynamically.

So, in your `SpringUtil` class, you can add the below method to remove the existing bean definition using `removeBeanDefinition()` and then add a new bean definition by using `registerBeanDefinition()`.

```
public void removeExistingAndAddNewBean(String beanId) {

   AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = 
                   applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
   BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
   registry.removeBeanDefinition(beanId);

    //create newBeanObj through GenericBeanDefinition

    registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanId, newBeanObj);
}
```

Comment: So, if this typecasting works, I can do this in any class where I can get my hands on `ApplicationContext`. Is it so?

Comment: But keep `ApplicationContext` only in `SpringUtil`, because it is not a good idea to expose `ApplicationContext` at too many places

Answer (score 2):

Instead of autowiring WebApplicationContext you can do

```
@Autowired
private GenericWebApplicationContext context;
```

Then you can do register new bean or remove old one and register new bean

```
AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
registry.removeBeanDefinition("myBean");
context.registerBean("myBean", MyBean.class, () -> new MyBean());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically create a bean with **injected dependencies** this way:

[AutowireCapableBeanFactory#createBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html)

> Fully create a new bean instance of the given class with the specified
> autowire strategy. All constants defined in this interface are
> supported here. Performs full initialization of the bean, including
> all applicable BeanPostProcessors.

```java
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
MyDynamicBean bean = (MyDynamicBean) factory.createBean(MyDynamicBean.class, AUTOWIRE_CONSTRUCTOR, false);
```

Comment: What about the name of the bean?