# Apache CXF how to deploy/run SOAP service on tomcat insted of in build jetty server

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, cxf

How to deploy **CXF SOAP web service** on tomcat instead of jetty server
if i try to use tomcat port to run `ServerFactoryBean` it is showing an error:

> port already running.

Is there any way to use tomcat instead of in-build jetty server?

Following is my code that i am trying to create a Server.

```
SoapBindingFactory bindingFactory = new SoapBindingFactory();
Bus bus = BusFactory.newInstance().createBus();
bindingFactory.setBus(bus);
bus.getExtension(BindingFactoryManager.class).registerBindingFactory("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/", bindingFactory);
bus.getExtension(BindingFactoryManager.class).registerBindingFactory("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http", bindingFactory);
Service service = new WSDLServiceFactory(bus, "wsdl path here", null).create();

ServerFactoryBean serverFactory = new ServerFactoryBean();
serverFactory.setBus(bus);

InboundRMHttpInvoker invoker = new InboundRMHttpInvoker(serviceImpl);
serverFactory.setInvoker(invoker);

serverFactory.setServiceBean(serviceImpl);
serverFactory.setDataBinding(service.getDataBinding());
serverFactory.setServiceName(service.getName());
serverFactory.setBindingId(service.getServiceInfos().get(0).getBindings().iterator().next().getBindingId());
serverFactory.setWsdlLocation("wsdl path");
serverFactory.setEndpointName(service.getServiceInfos().iterator().next().getEndpoints().iterator().next().getName());
serverFactory.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/services/sampleservice");
Server server = serverFactory.create();
```

If I use another port (other than tomcat) then it deploy my service on that port but how to run it on tomcat port.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider developing your application with Spring Boot or similar. When you deploy the war in the application container (eg tomcat), the ports configured in the container will be used.

**Update**

1. Configure a main class.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class AwesomeApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(AwesomeApp.class)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(AwesomeApp.class);
    }
}
```

2. Configure a CXF Servlet in `@Configuration` class.

```java
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> cxfServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(
                new CXFServlet(), "/services/*");
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return bean;
    }    
}
```

3. Implements the service.
4. Configure the Endpoint in `@Configuration` class and register the implementation.

```java
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    } 
    
    @Bean(name = "awesomeServiceImpl")
    public AwesomeServiceImpl awesomeServiceImpl()  {
        return new AwesomeServiceImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Endpoint awesomeEndpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), awesomeServiceImpl());
        endpoint.publish("/awesomeService");
        
        return endpoint;
    }   
}
```

5. Run your app and browse to `/services/awesomeService`.

Comment: yes, i am using spring boot and deploying the war file in tomcat

Comment: one more thing in my application user can deploy there own wsdl file , and that wsdl file i am passing to the CXF ( SoapBindingFactory  ) and CXF giving me the endpoint for that WSDL

Comment: In runtime?. Maybe you can register the Bean dynamically accessing the `applicationContext` and 
and registering it there. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051394/how-to-add-bean-instance-at-runtime-in-spring-webapplicationcontext

Comment: runtime means we have web application from there user can upload there WSDL file

Comment: Sorry..., I think I'm not understanding you. The user uploads the wsdl there and then what happens?. Where is or where do you load the implementation of the service?

Comment: ok, when i upload the WSDL in CXF then CXF server is creating service for that WSDL, and i have Request and Response Interceptor ( AbstractPhaseInterceptor ) for the service logic